# Why does Android Studio quick format (STRG ALT L) the code this way ?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, format

Like the question says, why is it formatted this way:

[image]

And not this way ?

[image]

Or am I just wrong and Android Studio Formats the Code as it should be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is following a specific code style. You can change it by going to **File** > **Settings** > **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Java** > **Wrapping and Braces** tab. In **Method call arguments**, uncheck **New line after '('**

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of taste.

Android Studio formats as it does to keep related elements (`new` and `Overrride`) close together.

Code Formattings are just conventions, there is no correct or incorrect way.